# Can anyone help me identify this lens? Pk 80-200mm autozoom

Tags: zoom, old-lenses

I have a lens I was going to try to sell on ebay but can't figure out what it is.  Doesn't appear to have a manufacturer name.  Made in Korea,  side has 22 16 11 8 5.6 4.6 PK.  Top has 80-200mm cct 1:4.5 mc 55 901382 cpc auto zoom  Case is Minolta Japan.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the lens? BTW, here's [a useful pictorial SLR lens mount identification guide](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html).

Comment: It would also be helpful to have descriptive info in the title. Otherwise, in a list of questions, that title could apply to... well, *any* lens.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a push pull Telephoto Zoom.
80-200mm f4.5

PK suggests its meant for a Pentax camera.

Comment: Bingo, that's it,  I was just trying to figure out how to post pics on the app, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

CPC was a cheap lens brand in the 1980's. They were cheap and not very well regarded. It is only worth about $10-20.

I believe this is the lens you have.....

[image]

[image]